# Change the text of a link on clicking the link using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am developing a social website like facebook in php. I have a page for displaying the messages for the user with two links,that is `reply` and `delete` at the right bottom corner for every messages in the inbox. My issue is that when I click the `reply` link,the text of both links should change to `post` and `back`.My html code is like this:

```
<div class="msgutil">
  <a href="" id="reply" >reply</a> 
  <a href="delete_message.php?msg_id=<?php echo $row_msg_id;?>" id="delete">delete</a>//dont check this
</div><!--end msgutil-->
```

My javascript code is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

    //action to be done if link name is reply which is present below the message box
    $("#reply").click(function(e) 
    {
        //action to be done if link name has changed from "reply" to "post" which is present below the message box
        if(document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML=="reply")
        {
            document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML="Post";
            document.getElementById('delete').innerHTML="Back";
            var idstr = document.getElementById('sender_id').value;
            $('<br/><form id="msgreply" name="msgreply" action="post_messages.php" method="post"> <label for="txt_subject"><strong>Subject:</strong></label><br/><input type="text" id="txt_subject" name="txt_subject"/><br/><label for="txt_message"><strong>Message:</strong></label><br/><input type="hidden" id="to_id" name="to_id" value="'+idstr+'"/><textarea name="txt_message" id="replyfield"></textarea></form>').insertAfter("#temp");
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML=="Post")
        {
            var message = document.getElementById('msgreply');
            message.submit();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    //action to be done if link name is delete which is present below the message box
    $("#delete").click(function(e) 
    {
        //action to be done if link name has changed from "reply" to "post" which is present below the message box
        if(document.getElementById('delete').innerHTML=="Back")
        {
            $("#msgreply").remove();
            document.getElementById('reply').innerHTML="reply";
            document.getElementById('delete').innerHTML="delete";
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

It works fine for the first message.If there are multiple messages in the inbox,on clicking the reply button of any messages other than first one, no action occurs.

Comment: if anyone downvotes,please tell me the reason

Comment: I'm done after reading your comment about not being sure if you're using jQuery. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {


      $('#id_of_reply').click(function(){
          $('#id_of_reply').html("POST");
          $('#id_of_delete').html("BACK");
      });

}
</script>
<a href="#" id="id_of_reply" >REPLY</a> <br><br>
<a href="" id="id_of_delete">DELETE</a>
```

And in href, put href="#". This will work.
This will put the fefault text of links as REPLY n DELETE and change them to POST n BACK on clicking "REPLY". Add code for whatever other things you wanna do on clicking "REPLY" in 
 $('#id_of_reply').click(function(){
And put anything to have default values outside this function.

Comment: @ sujit510 Do you mean to insert this code $('#id_of_reply').click(function(){
          $('#id_of_reply').html("POST");
          $('#id_of_delete').html("BACK");
      });                                                          inside my code??no need pf further edits???

Comment: @Anaz : See, I dont know what other functionality u need to work out in document.ready, you were stuck at changing the text of links when "Reply" is clicked. So I have posted code for this only. You have to keep other code for the other things you wanna achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you do `document.getElementById('reply')` it will get you the **first** element with `id='reply'`.

You could do something like this:

```
<div class="msgutil">
  <a href="" class="reply" >reply</a> 
  <a href="delete_message.php?msg_id=<?php echo $row_msg_id;?>" class="delete">delete</a><!-- dont check this -->
</div><!--end msgutil-->
```

And your code will be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

    //action to be done if link name is reply which is present below the message box
    $(".reply").click(function(e) 
    {
        var el = $(this);
        //action to be done if link name has changed from "reply" to "post" which is present below the message box
        if(el.text() == "reply") // Changed from innerHtml to the text() method
        {
            var deleteEl = $(this).parent().find('> .delete'); // Gets the delete element relatively to this one
            el.text("Post");
            deleteEl.text("Back");

            var idstr = $('#sender_id').value;
            $('<br/><form id="msgreply" name="msgreply" action="post_messages.php" method="post"> <label for="txt_subject"><strong>Subject:</strong></label><br/><input type="text" id="txt_subject" name="txt_subject"/><br/><label for="txt_message"><strong>Message:</strong></label><br/><input type="hidden" id="to_id" name="to_id" value="'+idstr+'"/><textarea name="txt_message" id="replyfield"></textarea></form>').insertAfter("#temp");
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else if(el.html() == "Post")
        {
            var message = $('#msgreply');
            message.submit();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    //action to be done if link name is delete which is present below the message box
    $(".delete").click(function(e) 
    {
        var el = $(this);
        //action to be done if link name has changed from "reply" to "post" which is present below the message box
        if(el.text() == "Back")
        {
            var replyEl = $(this).parent().find('> .reply'); // Gets the reply element relatively to this one

            $("#msgreply").remove();
            replyEl.text("reply");

            el.text("delete");
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

---

Instead of getting `$('#reply')` and `$('#delete')` which only get the first element with that id since id's should be unique, we use:

```
$(this).parent().find('> .delete');
```

It does this:

- Takes the current element - `<a href="" class="reply">reply</a>`
- Finds it's parent - `<div class="msgutil"></div>`
- Finds an element with a `.delete` class - `<a href="" class="delete">delete</a>`

You should do the same to all other elements you have with the same id.

**PS1:** As you can see I replaced all the `getElementById('something')` with `$('#something')`, if your'e using an awesome library like jQuery use it all the time.

**PS2:** You can't do comments in html like `//dont check this` instead use `<!-- dont check this -->` :)

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to use classes instead of ids, try it now

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="msgutil" id="msglinks_<?php echo $row_msg_id;?>">
<a href="">reply</a> 
<a href="delete_message.php?msg_id=<?php echo $row_msg_id;?>" class="delete">delete</a><!-- dont check this -->
</div><!--end msgutil-->
```

and in the reply click event get the row_msg_id and replace both the links, because changing the text alone will not be good, still it will work as reply and delete event...so change both url,

```
$("#msglinks_"+row_msg_id).html("url links");
```